# Why don't some search bars work with Python requests?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

For whatever reason, I can't seem to be able to get this request to actually search in the search bar. There are 2 search bars on this website, one on the top right of the header, and also one on the main page. Maybe that has something to do with this? Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
beername = "guinness"
url = 'https://untappd.com/search?'
search_params = {'query': beername}
r = requests.get(url, params=search_params)
r = requests.post(url, params=search_params) # <-doesn't work either
s = soup(r.content, 'html.parser')
containers = s.findAll('div', {'class': "beer-item "})
print(len(containers)) # this returns 0 right now
```

Answer (score 0):

The query tag name is `"q"`, not `"query"`.

Enjoy responsibly!